# How can I set yate to be my default tel: protocol handler?

Tags: linux-mint, browser, voip, telephony

On [this site](http://www.frigidaire.com/kitchen-appliances/ranges/) I clicked on the support link and a phone number popped up.  It was formatted via the `tel:` protocol, and as such was underlined and highlighted like a web link.  On my phone, clicking on such a link opens my default dialer and places the call.

When links are not formatted via this protocol, my browser's Google voice plugin usually auto-detects the phone number and gives me a chance to call via Google voice.  It would be nice if I could also do this for `tel:` formatted numbers, or better yet, as I don't always have a voice session open, set `tel:` formatted numbers be handled by `yate`.

**How can I fix my browser's handling of the `tel:` protocol links such that it opens in `yate` or google voice?**

- In Chromium I get a warning saying that xdg-open will be used to handle the link, but when I click 'Launch Application' nothing happens.
- In Firefox, clicking on the link leads me to a blank page with the url tel:18003744432
- In Konqueror clicking on the link produces this error:

  ```
  Access by untrusted page to tel:18003744432 denied.
  ```

I'm using Linux Mint 16 KDE x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407393/15658) for pointing me in the right direction with the mimetype handler.

I ended up creating a simple desktop entry to open links in Hangouts. I think the location for this will vary by distro, but for me this is what worked (I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04). This just converts the `tel:` number into a URL that tells hangouts to make a phone call, and lets `xdg-open` handle it so it will open in your default browser.

**~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list**

```
[Added Associations]
x-scheme-handler/tel=hangouts.desktop
```

**~/.local/share/applications/hangouts.desktop**

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=bash -c 'xdg-open "https://hangouts.google.com/?action=chat&pn=${0//tel:/}"' %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

To explain the code, it passes `%u` (which will be the `tel:` link) into an inline bash script as the `$0` param. Then `${0//tel:/}` strips the `tel:` from the front of it, leaving you with the number. That number then gets passed in to the hangouts URL.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tel` to yate's .desktop file will tell XDG-compliant tools to use it to handle `tel:` URLs. Also, make sure that the `Exec` entry contains `%u` or `%U` so that the executable is passed the URL(s).

[XDG Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by installing the Chromium extension `Dialr`.

However, I'm still hoping someone will write the needed tel.protocol file.